# Error message 'No handlers could be found for logger "multiprocessing"' using Celery

Tags: python, logging, rabbitmq, celery

[RabbitMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ) now seems to be working correctly. However, when I try

```
python -m celery.bin.celeryd --loglevel=INFO`
```

(regular `celeryd` doesn't work), I get the error

> No handlers could be found for logger "multiprocessing"`).

Here's the full output (redacted slightly):

```
[2011-06-06 02:08:08,105: WARNING/MainProcess] -------------- celery@blahblah v2.2.6
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** ---   . broker:      amqplib://blah@localhost:5672/vhost
- ** ----------   . loader:      celery.loaders.default.Loader
- ** ----------   . logfile:     [stderr]@INFO
- ** ----------   . concurrency: 2
- ** ----------   . events:      OFF
- *** --- * ---   . beat:        OFF
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [Queues]
 --------------   . celery:      exchange:celery (direct) binding:celery


[Tasks]
  . tasks.add
[2011-06-06 02:08:08,812: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@blahblah has started
.
No handlers could be found for logger "multiprocessing"
No handlers could be found for logger "multiprocessing"
```

I'd really like to get this set up properly, so I can move on to using it with Django!

(It is not my first *no handlers found* error, but I'm having trouble finding anything on the web regarding this...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be something strange in the way celery initializes logging.  If I put the switch `--logfile=yourfile.log` on the command-line, it works reliably, but reading the logging from the config gives unreliable results including the stuff you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that all processes started from the main process also set up logging correctly. [Here's a post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-logging-with-multiprocessing.html) which discusses how best to do logging with `multiprocessing`. Though that discusses features with came in with Python 3.2, you can also get this functionality for earlier Python versions - see [this other post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/10/logutils-using-recent-logging-features.html).

**Update:** The point is that each process needs to initialise logging, and you need to arrange this in your code, in a similar way to what is done in the example in the first post: see `listener_configurer` and `worker_configurer`. You can use `logutils` to help you, but the main thing is to realise that each process needs to configure logging, if you are to avoid that "no handlers could be found" message.

Comment: I'm still confused at to where that code would go then. Do I include it somewhere in Python? Do I modify Celery itself? Do I include it as part of the sample "first steps with Celery" mini-app? If any of the above, where do I put it? What do I call it? I understand your solution in theory but unfortunately I don't know how to apply it - I sense that at some point I lack a fundamental level of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the log file directory exists the and processes has write permission to the log directory.

I faced similar issue , after creating log file location directory the problem went away.