# Scheduling a regular event: Cron/Cron alternatives (including Celery)

Tags: python, windows, django, linux, cron

Something I've had interest in is regularly running a certain set of actions at regular time intervals. Obviously, this is a task for [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), right?

Unfortunately, the Internet seems to be in a bit of disagreement there.

Let me elaborate a little about my setup. First, my development environment is in Windows, while my production environment is hosted on [Webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com/why-webfaction/) (Linux). There is no real cron on Windows, right? Also, I use [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)! And what's suggested for Django?

*[Celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/introduction.html)* of course! Unfortunately, setting up Celery has been more or less a literal nightmare for me - please see *[Error message 'No handlers could be found for logger “multiprocessing”' using Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244554)*. And this is only ONE of the problems I've had with Celery. Others include a socket error which it I'm the only one ever to have gotten the problem.

Don't get me wrong, Celery seems REALLY cool. Unfortunately, there seems to be a lack of support, and some odd limitations built into its preferred backend, [RabbitMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ). Unfortunately, no matter how cool a program is, if it doesn't work, well, it doesn't work!

That's where I hope all of you can come in. I'd like to know about cron or a cron-equivalent, which can be set up similarly (preferably identically) in both a Windows and a Linux environment.

(I've been struggling with Celery for about two weeks now and unfortunately I think it's time to toss in the towel and give up on it, at least for now.)

Comment: Why would you want to develop on Windows but deploy on Linux? It seems like you are setting yourself up for a lot of headaches like these.

Comment: Not entirely my choice.  I've considered changing over one of my computers or partitioning it, but ultimately that has its own shares of equivalent problems.  Just looking to make the best of the situation as it is now.

Comment: Wubi installer makes it easy for u to dual-boot to ubuntu now.

Comment: for people who are still trying the original initial way i.e for setting up celery check this (http://aameer.github.io/celery-an-asynchronous-task-queue-job-queue/) and for setting up rabbitmq on webfaction check this (http://aameer.github.io/installing-rabbitmq-on-webfaction/). Moreover if you want to daemonize them check this (http://aameer.github.io/circus-as-an-alternative-to-supervisor/) hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple, non-Celery way to approach things would be to create  [custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) to perform your asynchronous or scheduled tasks.

Then, on Windows, you use the `at` command to schedule these tasks. On Linux, you use `cron`.

I'd also strongly recommend ditching Windows if you can for a development environment. Your life will be so much better on Linux or even Mac OSX. Re-purpose a spare or old machine with Ubuntu for example, or run Ubuntu in a VM on your Windows box.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem, and held off trying to solve it with celery (too complicated) or cron (external to application) and ended up finding [Advanced Python Scheduler](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/index.html). Only just started using it but it seems reasonably mature and stable, has decent documentation and will take a number of scheduling formats (e.g. cron style).

From the [documentation](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/intervalschedule.html), running a function at a specific interval.

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()
def hello_world():
    print "hello world"
sched.add_interval_job(hello_world,seconds=10)
```

This is non-blocking, and I run something pretty identical by simply importing the module from my `urls.py`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/andybak/django-cron

Triggered by a single cron task but all the scheduling and configuration is done in Python.

Answer (score 1):

[Django Chronograph](https://github.com/jgeewax/django-chronograph) is a great alternative. You only need to setup one cron then do everything in django admin. You can schedule tasks/commands from django management.